# How does the constructor set the default value of a class' members?

Tags: c#

According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors#parameterless-constructors), Constructors enable the programmer to set default values, limit instantiation, and write code that is flexible and easy to read.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new MyClass();
        Console.WriteLine($"i: {a.i}, b: {a.b}"); //result --> i: 0, b: False
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int i;
    public bool b;
    public MyClass() { }
}
```

My constructor doesn't have a single line of code. At what point the members of my class get initialized? And what if I don't provide a default constructor but rather a constructor that take some parameters? The documentation doesn't explain that assertion. Do codes similar to this get injected?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int i;
    public bool b;
    public MyClass()
    {
        i = default;
        b = default;
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Note that `default` is always equivalent to zero bytes. Setting each field to `default` might be implemented in the runtime as a single `memset(...)` call. The runtime may also skip that step if it can prove that you initialised all members before reading them.

Comment: Yes, second code sample is similar, default values will be set

Comment: Fields and properties are implicitly assigned the data types default value, typically zero for value types, and null for reference types, this is done before the constructor is invoked.

Comment: @Matthew To put it more precisely, the code to set the fields if they have a default value `= something` is generated by the compiler as part of the constructor, but before any user code. But if no value is given, then it is as you say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[ECMA-334 specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_5th_edition_december_2017.pdf)**, which defines the C# standard, says this:

> **10.4.2  - Initially assigned variables**
>
> The following categories of variables are classified as initially assigned:
>
> - Static variables.
> - Instance variables of class instances.
> - Instance variables of initially assigned struct variables.
> - Array elements.
> - Value parameters.
> - Reference parameters.
> - Variables declared in a `catch` clause or a `foreach` statement.

So the compiler ensures that these variables are always set to `default`. This is easily backed up by the CLR, which always initializes all such variable locations (note that local variables are specifically **not** in the above list).

**[ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf)**, which defines the CLR, says:

> **I.8.11.2 - Field definitions**
>
> *snip*
> Fields not marked as static define the representation of a value of a type by defining the substructure of the value (see §I.8.4.1). Locations for such fields are created within every value of the type whenever a new value is constructed. They are initialized during construction of the new value.

Comment: Wow you hit such a trivial question with both barrels + 1,

Comment: Problem is: trivial questions sometimes have non-obvious answers, and tend to attract a lot of misconceptions even by the more experienced *answerers*. The other answer mentioned the heap, an entirely irrelevant point, and not necessarily true.

Comment: I agree, personally i would have just answered with, class fields and auto properties get set to *default* unless set by an initializer or constructor. then [given this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values) as such I thought the ecma references were a good, and truthfully well above and beyond the reasoning of this question.   :)

Comment: @Charlieface, May be the point is irrelevant to you. I just wanted to point out that though int and bool are primitive types, in this case they are allocated space in heap.

Comment: @anandshukla As I already explained to you, not necessarily are they allocated on the heap. And what the *significance* of their location is, I don't know. The compiler and CLR make certain guarantees around their usage and behaviour, that is all we need to know. My favourite explanation when people ask "where are variables stored?" is "they may as well be stored on the moon, for all you should care".

Answer (score 1):

When you define a class it is present virtually like blueprint of any design. So When you move to its implementation it becomes reality. Same goes for object and classes in any Object oriented language. When you define class, you basically define blueprint it does not exist yet but when you create object of class, it is created in memory.  So in your first case where you have constructor without any arguments when you create object memory space is reserved based on its member and types.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int i;
    public bool b;
    public MyClass() { }
 }
```

In this case when you create object, memory is reserved for int and bool. it does not matter whether you have parameterized constructor where you are assigning values to class members or not. Memory space is reserved with default values for int and bool in heap.

Comment: Not sure what the heap has to do with anything. For example, what happens if you declare a struct as a local variable and stop the debugger before initialization. Also, you could be running in a (as yet unavailable) version of the CLR that does escape analysis and allocates objects on the stack

Comment: If you stop debugger before initialization but you have declare struct, memory will be allocated in stack with default values. Size of struct won't change event after initialization.

Comment: Precisely my point: even a struct allocated on the stack is actually initialized before any code is run. What has size got do with anything, no-one mentioned that?